# PHP cURL creates empty file name only (0 bytes) - not transferring actual file

Tags: php, curl, azure-ad-graph-api, form-data, microsoft-graph-files

I'm using a File Type input to pass FormData ($_FILES['files']) to PHP via Ajax

My PHP cURL looks like this:

```
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . <token>, 
    "Host: graph.microsoft.com",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
    "Content-Length: 0",
);

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$postfile = curl_init('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' . <userid> . '/drive/root:/<folder>/' . $filename . ':/content'); 
curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($postfile,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($postfile,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($postfile,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$result = curl_exec($postfile);
curl_close($postfile);
```

This creates a file in the correct folder of the user's OneDrive with the correct extension and everything, but they are all empty (0 bytes).

I've tested this with many files of different types for hours, and it's always the same.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So you are trying to upload an existing file rather than create a new file?

Comment: @AllenWu yes, that's right. I'm trying to upload existing files from my computer to OneDrive.

Comment: But I didn't see where you get the file from your local machine. Use `file_get_contents` to get the file and pass it when you call the Microsoft Graph API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262443/upload-file-to-office-365-onedrive-business-account-using-php-curl?answertab=votes#tab-top and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708226/how-upload-large-files-to-onedrive-using-php-curl?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Comment: The second answer is for uploading large file (>4M) to O365. But it should be the same for getting file using `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @AllenWu shouldn't that be available from $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']?

Comment: Didn't try `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`. Did you try with `file_get_contents`?

Comment: @AllenWu I finally got it!!! After trying for days now! Is 2pm too early for a drink? hahaha

Comment: Glad to know that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have mising filedata
Try add following to your curl

```
$fh_res = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

Comment: LuRy thanks for trying, but that didn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Sofistikat this seems to be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251886/curl-post-file-to-onedrive

Comment: LuRy that was one of the first search results I found, and it wasn't successful either. I just tried it again without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with the following:

```
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filecon = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'r');
    $filesize = filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Bearer " . <token>, 
        "Host: graph.microsoft.com",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: " . $filesize,
    );

    $postfile = curl_init('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' . <userid> . '/drive/root:/<folder>/' . $filename . ':/content'); 
    
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($postfile,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_INFILE, $filecon);
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);

    $result = curl_exec($postfile);
    curl_close($postfile);
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for PHP cURL upload to OneDrive!